# Iterating over a List and waiting for a Future to complete in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I have the following scenario:

- a `List[Building]` collection I'll call `buildings`
- a `def getAddress(building: Building): Future[Address]` function
- the result should be a `List[BuildingWithAddress]` collection

I want to iterate over the `List[Building]` and for each element call `getAddress` and wait for it to complete so that I can create a new object of type `BuildingWithAddress` and store it in a collection that I'll then return to the caller.

I thought I'd use a for-comprehension but it turns out that something along the line of this won't really work:

```
for {
    building <- listOfBuildings
    address <- getAddress(building)
    buildingWithAddress = BuildingWithAddress(name = building.name, town = address.town)
} yield buildingWithAddress
```

I also thought on using `flatMap` to iterate over the list and then do the same for the address but the types are different and it won't work.

I tried with a `forEach` but then again the forEach isn't waiting on the Future to complete.

What's the solution for such a simple use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot usually combine different monads in a single `for` comprehension (except for scala's collection-likes). Here you want to combine the `Future` and `List` monads, which cannot be done this way.
If you want to do this in a "sequential" way (waiting for previous future operations to finish before starting new ones) you need to use a `ListT` monad transformer from scalaz (or cats) like this:

```
import scalaz.ListT
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._

implicit executor: ExecutionContext = ...

def fromList[A](x: List[A]) = ListT(Future.successful(x))
def single[A](x: Future[A]) = ListT(x.map(List(_)))

(for {
  building <- fromList(listOfBuildings)
  address <- single(getAddress(building))
  buildingWithAddress = BuildingWithAddress(name = building.name, town = address.town)
} yield buildingWithAddress).run
```

Which will result in a `Future[List[...]]` as you need.
Alternative solution if you are fine with calling the `getAddress` functions in parallel:

```
Future.traverse(listOfBuildings)(building =>
  getAddress(building).map(address =>
    BuildingWithAddress(name = building.name, town = address.town)))
```

This is traverses the List "applicatively" (meaning: in parallel).

Comment: Missed out an argument from the last code, here is the fixed version: `Future.traverse(listOfBuildings)(building =>
  getAddress(building).map(address => BuildingWithAddress(name = building.name, town = address.town)))`

Comment: Use the `edit` button at the bottom of your post to edit/correct your answer. Much better/clearer than trying to add corrections in the comments.

Comment: @mpetruska Thanks, I used the parallel solution of your answer and it worked a charm and it's definitely clean.

Answer (score 3):

use `Future.sequence`

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val l = List(1,2,3)
val futureList: Seq[Future[Int]] = l.map(e=>Future(e))

//conversion List[Future[T]] => Future[List[T]]
val singleFuture: Future[Seq[Int]] = Future.sequence(futureList)
singleFuture.map(_.length)
```